# QEMU MacOS host Linux quest audio

Tags: macos, audio, homebrew, virtualization

I installed qemu via brew. Successfully installed ubuntu 18.04 desktop as a qemu guest.

Following is the start up command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \                                                                                  
-show-cursor \
-M q35,accel=hvf,usb=off,vmport=off \
-cpu host -smp 4 -m 2048 \
-overcommit mem-lock=off \
-overcommit cpu-pm=off \
-rtc base=utc,clock=host \
-audiodev id=coreaudio,driver=coreaudio \
\
-device virtio-blk-pci,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x2,drive=ssd1 \
-device virtio-net-pci,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x3,netdev=nic1,mac=52:54:98:76:54:33 \
-device virtio-tablet-pci,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x4 \
-device virtio-vga \
\
-drive id=ssd1,file=/Users/js/code/VM/qemu/u64d01.qcow2,if=none,format=qcow2 \
-netdev user,id=nic1,ipv4=on,ipv6=on,hostname=u64d01,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

Ubuntu desktop startup correctly and is responsive. However I am not able to get audio working. It just show "Dummy Output" in Settings->Sound.

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QEMU devices are typically split into [two parts](https://www.qemu.org/2018/02/09/understanding-qemu-devices/), host backend and guest hardware device. The backend specifies how data from the guest hardware is processed on the host, e.g. audio can be recorded to a file or rerouted straight to the host output. Guest hardware device is a virtual hardware device presented in the guest. The model was introduced to QEMU audio [since 4.2](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2020/01/qemu-sound-audiodev/).

In the command line you specified Core Audio as host backend, but no hardware device was added, that's why you don't see it in the guest. You need to add a PCI sound card, e.g. Intel HDA and bind its output to the coreaudio backend:

```
-device intel-hda -device hda-output,audiodev=coreaudio
```

Full list of sound hardware is available in `-device help`.